# Weird error in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to obtain the last value that I put in.

I am trying to obtain the number on which my article is. So I use this query:

```
 $totalPages= mysql_query("SELECT page FROM `easy_db`.`article` ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT 1")  or die(mysql_error());
```

The value that I get is 6.

Why 6? I truncated the table..and tried again and I get 6 again.. It should be 1.

Another question, I want to enforce types in php..

I try to enforce an Int, but it doesnt seem to work:

```
 $page=(int) $totalPages/10;
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted some data.  For the last article_id, what is the page?

Comment: You might want to consider asking your other question as another question here on stackoverflow since it isn't related to your first.

Comment: okay. someone answered me about the first question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mysql_query](https://www.php.net/mysql_query) returns a resource handle, not the result of the query itself. See the PHP manual for some basic examples of [how to query a database](https://www.php.net/mysql_query). For example:

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT page FROM `easy_db`.`article` ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT 1")  or die(mysql_error());

if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $totalPages=$row['page'];
}
```

With regard to your second question, pay attention to the [operator precedence rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) - the (int) operator has a higher precedence than division, so is carried out before the division. Thus, you can get a floating point result. Alternatively try one of these

```
$page = (int)($totalPages/10); #rounds down

$page=round($totalPages/10); #rounds up or down as appropriate
```

Also checkout [floor()](http://php.net/floor) and [ceil()](http://php.net/ceil) as alternatives to round, as they are often useful when writing pagination calculations.

Comment: Thanks. and can you tell me how I can enforce types in php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mysql_insert_id()` function in php to retrieve the id of the last inserted row.

[mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: The problem is that I need to retrieve the page numebr which isnt an id. and I do the insert only after I do the select statement. So that isnt a solution

Comment: Well using the id, you can then easily retrieve the page number.

Answer (score 1):

You should use mysql_insert_id(); immediately after your insert statement.